# Object of child class cannot call its own methods

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, extends, upcasting

If `c` is a `ChildClass` object then why can't it call methods of `ChildClass`?
Like:

```
ParentClass c=new ChildClass(); //Here ChildClass extends ParentClass
```

In particular:

```
Object s=new StringBuffer();
```

Here `s` is object of `StringBuffer`, but `s.append(null)` is compile time error. Why so?

Comment: Because the type of your **reference variable** is `ParentClass` and Parent Class is clueless about the functionality of its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is declared to be a `ParentClass`.  Therefore, all the compiler knows about it is that it is a `ParentClass` or **some** subclass of it.  Suppose some other statement reassigned `c` somewhere:

```
c = new SomeOtherChildClass();
```

which is legal, because `SomeOtherChildClass` is also a subclass of `ParentClass`, and you've told the compiler that `c` can be any `ParentClass`.  Now, if the compiler sees

```
c.methodOfChildClass();
```

how will it know that `c` is a `ChildClass` and not a `SomeOtherChildClass` that doesn't have that method?

P.S. If you're sure `c` is really a `ChildClass`, at some point, you can get it to call a `ChildClass` method by downcasting:

```
((ChildClass)c).methodOfChildClass();
```

The cast will cause the compiler to see `c` as a `ChildClass`; at runtime, the program will check to make sure `c` really is a `ChildClass` or else the program will throw `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the compiler's job to make sure that you don't call any methods that don't match the variable that you're calling it on.  To assist the compiler with this, we give all variables a "type".  A type might be a primitive type like "int", or a class, an enum or an interface.  If it's a class, an interface, or an enum; then the methods that are listed in that class, interface or enum are the ones that the compiler will let you use, on that variable.

The "type" of the variable isn't necessarily the same as the "class" of the object that the variable refers to.  In your example, the type is `Object`, but the class is `StringBuffer`.  But the type, not the class, is what the compiler uses to check that your method calls are OK; because the compiler can't be expected to know the class of every object that you're ever likely to use a variable to refer to.

If the language didn't work this way, there'd be no point in variables having types at all.  That's the way Javascript works - everything is declared as `var` and there's no real type system.  When we say Java is "statically typed", we mean that we have to give variables types, and that doing so helps the compiler to protect us from misusing our variables.

Answer (score 1):

because compiler doesn't know that reference `s` is going to be referring to an instance of `StringBuffer` at runtime and `Java` is [statically typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice)

Comment: what is statically typed language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the object to use methods of the instance

```
Object s = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer s2 = (StringBuffer) s;
s2.append(null);
```

despite being an instance of StringBuffer, it remains of type Object, and Object not have method append

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast your object to  stringbuffer type or you have to declare  s object like this stringbuffer s =new stringbuffer() then you can   call all method of this class